# Extracting subgraphs (cliques) within graph on Netlogo

Tags: networking, netlogo, subgraph, clique

I have a netlogo question. I have some graph structures of nodes connected with (undirected) links. I need to figure out which is the smallest subgraph within one of these structures. Basically subgraph means which nodes are all connected between each other. So if I have a structure of 5 nodes and node 1 is connected to 2 and 3; node 2 to 3, 1 and 4; and node 3 to 1, 2 and 5 I need to detect the subgraph of nodes 1, 2 and 3 since they're all interconnected.

Is there an easy way to do this or is it basically not computationally possible?

Edit: I figured out that if I use the netlogo extension nw I can use the nw:maximal-cliques method to calculate what I want. Although now I have another problem. I'm trying to fill up a list of the lists of the cliques this way

```
let lista-cliques [nw:maximal-cliques] of turtles with [guild = g]
```

lista-cliques is usually of length two but the first element which should be a list of the turtles of the clique is a list like this

```
[[[nobody] [nobody] [nobody] [nobody]...etc
```

with a length of 300 when the graphs made by turtles with guild = g are around 2-8 turtles in length. Is the call to nw:maximal-cliques well made?

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Edit 2: I figured how to fix the length of the list by doing this

```
let lista-cliques (list ([nw:maximal-cliques] of turtles with [guild = g]))
```

Now the list is not of 300 nodes but equal to the amount of nodes on the graph with nodes with guild = g.

That means that

```
length item 1 lista-cliques
```

is equal to

```
count turtles with [guild = g]
```

which is also evidently wrong since I can see graphs with nodes connected to only one or two nodes. I think I'm getting closer but I don't know why nw:maximal-cliques is not creating a list of the maximal-cliques but a list of all the nodes on the graph.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `nw:maximal-cliques` is not quite correct.

I think that what you are trying to express by specifying `of turtles with [guild = g]` is something like "taking into account only the turtles that are part of guild *g*", but what it actually means to NetLogo is "run the reporter that precedes `of` for each turtle that are part of guild *g* and make a list out of that". (Just like, e.g., `[color] of turtles` will run the `[color]` reporter block once for each turtle and build a list of colors with the results.)

`nw:maximal-cliques` is a primitive that operates on *the whole network*, so you don't want to run it once for each turtle. And just like most primitives in the `nw` extension, you need to tell it which turtles and links to operate on by using the `nw:set-snapshot` primitive.

I think you can achieve what you want by simply doing:

```
nw:set-snapshot (turtles with [guild = g]) links
let lista-cliques nw:maximal-cliques
```

(Note that `nw:set-snapshot` takes a static "picture" of your network on which further calls to `nw` primitives operate. If something changes in your network, you need to call `nw:set-snapshot` to take a new picture. This will probably change in a future version of the extension.)